# How to remove (or set) local notification badge in app icons - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, badge, flutter-notification

I want to remove or set the notification icon of my application, what should I do?
I use the `flutter_local_notifications` package, and there is no property for removing or customizing the badge icon of the application.

Also, in default, it seems like this:

[image: android]

Comment: also the notification type is scheduled if you need to know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the notifications, you can handle it like the **below image**. To update it, you can use the `flutter_app_badger` package as **Rami AI Debs** said.

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I integrated my app with 3rd party chatting library, they should send the notification count with the notification data, so we used [flutter badger](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_app_badger) package to control the app badge number.

Comment: thanks for replying, I posted my answer (another way to remove)

Comment: great! I upvoted your answer. keep it up! @alperefesahin

Answer (score 0):

Here’s how you can disable notification badges directly with flutter_local_notifications:

```
AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
  '0',
  'Release reminders',
  channelShowBadge: false, // Disables badges
);
```

By setting channelShowBadge to false, you can disable notification badges for this specific channel. Make sure to pass this AndroidNotificationDetails instance when you create a notification.
https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_local_notifications/latest/flutter_local_notifications/AndroidNotificationDetails/channelShowBadge.html

I hope this helps!